# OU Information Not Available In Azure After Syncing User From On Prem Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have created one organizational unit inside my active directory and added a user inside that OU.

> **DistinguishedName : CN=Alex Shaun,OU=TestOU,DC=mydomain,DC=com
>
> Enabled           : True
>
> GivenName         : Alex
> Name : Alex Shaun
>
> ObjectClass       : user
> ObjectGUID        : 16fc9afc-02a5-474f-8837-4e71853y1ceb
>
> SamAccountName    : alex
> SID               : S-1-5-21-233531163-xxxxxxx-2764101054-1604
>
> Surname           : Shaun
>
> UserPrincipalName : alex@mydomain.com**

After doing I synced that user into my azure using azure ad connect. Now I am using Microsoft Azure API to get user information but it does not contain any information regarding OU.

```
        {
        "businessPhones": [],
        "displayName": "Alex Shaun",
        "givenName": "Alex",
        "jobTitle": null,
        "mail": null,
        "mobilePhone": null,
        "officeLocation": null,
        "preferredLanguage": null,
        "surname": "Shaun",
        "userPrincipalName": "alex@mydomain.com",
        "id": "xxxx-0744-47cb-ad48-xxxxxxxx"
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Active Directory is a flat structure containing user, groups & computer objects

**Azure Active Directory does not have OUs**

So, you would not  be  able to see OU information in the  Azure Active Directory

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch **onPremisesDistinguishedName** property which contains OU.

It is returned only on $select. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=onPremisesDistinguishedName